# In python dataframe, how do you leave values as blanks if None is picked up?

Tags: python, dataframe

My code's function is to pickup values within a certain tolerance (100 ppm tolerance) from the known values.

The data to be picked up look like:

```
col1      col2
1000      10000
1050      20000
2000      30000
```

and so forth (up to 400 ish rows). Below is a section of the code that picks up from the pickup list (values similar to col1):

```
for files in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(files, engine='python')
    matches = pd.DataFrame(index=pickuplist['mass'],
                        columns=df.set_index(list(df.columns)).index,
                        dtype=bool)
    for index, exp_mass, intensity in df.itertuples():
        matches[exp_mass] = abs(matches.index - exp_mass)/matches.index < ppm/1e6
        if (len(matches[exp_mass])== 0):
            matches[exp_mass] = None
    results3 = matches.any().reset_index(name='a')[matches.any().values]
```

Each file's structure is similar to the example table shown above (col1, col2, and an empty column).  The pickup list looks like:

```
col1
1000.04
1050.02
2000.04
```

The current code when run does pickup the wanted values and outputs them as:

```
col1     col2
1000.04  10000
1050.02  20000
2000.04  30000
```

However, I want to leave blanks if there is none picked up. For example, if a pickup list contains a value in col1 of 1647.58 and there is nothing within 100 ppm tolerance of 1647.58 in the data, then the matches dataframe for that 1647.58 will be empty spaces:

```
col1     col2
1000.04  10000
1050.02  20000

2000.04  30000

if (len(matches[exp_mass])== 0):
    matches[exp_mass] = None
```

I thought the above part would do the trick but I guess I was wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening it's that you are trying to update a variable in python while iterating it. This is not possible in python, check [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/341179/why-does-python-only-make-a-copy-of-the-individual-element-when-iterating-a-list) for an explanation but simplified imagine you had this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1000.04, 1000], [1050.02, 2000], [2000.04, 3000]]), columns=('col1', 'col2'))

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['col1'] == 1000.04:
        row['col1'] == np.nan

print(df)
```

You would think that this would change the value of the first row however if you execute it you would see that doesn't happen.
In order to alter your data frame you need to change like this:

```
df.loc[df['col1'] == 1000.04, ['col1', 'col2']] = np.nan
print(df)
```